# OpenGeo Suite - Possible to create input form

Tags: javascript, boundless-suite, html

Is it possible to create a user input form such as a simple HTML form to take user input?

The aim of this is to add the user input to the geom data in the DB.

Comment: OpenGeo Suite is a server suite of software, not a client data editor.  You may use other geospatial client editor apps. such as QGIS or OpenLayers for performing edits on geospatial data.

Comment: Thank you. That was my assumption in the end. The edits aren't necessarily related directly to the data. The idea is based on a ticket system where a "ticket" is created to go and inspect some geo-spatial feature. Only after the ticket has been completed is it linked to the spatial data. I will take a look into OpenLayers then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GXP (which is used by GeoExplorer, depends on GeoExt) has some components for this, FeatureEditorForm and FeatureEditorGrid:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/FeatureEditorForm.js
https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/FeatureEditorGrid.js

They will use a WFS DescribeFeatureType request as the basis but will allow for customization.